# No definition for 'DisplayBox_TextChanged'

Tags: c#, error-handling

```
Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.calculator_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayBox_TextChanged' and no extension method 'DisplayBox_TextChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.calculator_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:enter code here

Line 18:     <tr>
Line 19:         <td colspan="5">
Line 20:             <asp:TextBox ID="DisplayBox" runat="server" 
Line 21:                 ontextchanged="DisplayBox_TextChanged" Width="268px"></asp:TextBox>
Line 22:         </td>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class calculator : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete example of the code that causes this error.

Comment: For me, the compiler was saying i had no method. I did have the method, but i got some errors inside it. I ignored those errors when compiling and it got me this same error message. I just commented those error lines and compiled again. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support for the TextChanged event of the DisplayBox implement the DisplayBox_TextChanged event in the .cs file.

```
protected void DisplayBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //logic...
}
```

If you are not interested in TextChanged event then remove the below part from the XAML file (in line 21).

```
ontextchanged="DisplayBox_TextChanged"
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like, from the little bit of code you provided, that you are trying to respond to the `ontextchanged` event, but you did not implement the `DisplayBox_TextChanged` method to handle the event. Either remove the `ontextchanged="DisplayBox_TextChanged` from the code above or create a method called `DisplayBox_TextChanged`

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind file you need to implement the DisplayBox_TextChanged method.

It would look something like this

```
protected void DisplayBox_TextChanged( EventArgs e )
{
    //code here
}
```

MSDN for method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: shouldn't that be `protected void DisplayBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

> from project explorer right click on the project and choose add reference and add the dll file StructureMap.dll it may be in the bin directory of the project

http://forums.asp.net/t/1381741.aspx/1

JMax

Comment: Umm...this answer makes absolutely no sense and doesn't appear to even relate to the question/error.

Comment: I almost responded the same as the others, but in doing some research about the problem, it looks to be more like an MVC issue (although the original poster gave no detail). It looked more like MVC because their comment about: "and no extension method 'DisplayBox_TextChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.calculator_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I did some research on that and that is why I submitted the link.